# Implementing Facebook's Like feature using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have a use case to implement a 'like' feature for messages using `GCM`. One approach that comes to mind is to make each post a 'topic' and then send all likes on a post as a separate `GCM` message on that topic.

However, in order to achieve this, the client has to register for each topic corresponding to the post that it has loaded on the `UI` in real time. This brings me to the following questions:

1. This is approach right?
2. How long will it take for a client's subscription to a topic to reflect at `GCM`'s end? Same for unsubscription?
3. Can I get a list of all subscribers to a given topic?